# permutation and combination

Tags: sql, permutation, combinations, cross-join

i have a table with only one column consisiting of 5 colours-

```
colour
-------
red
black
white
green 
orange
```

I want to get all the combinations like

(red,orange)
(black,white) 
.
.
.
etc except the identical ones.i have tried to cross join the table with itself .

```
select * 
from table1 cross join table1
```

but i did not get the desired answer.it returned all the combinations.also identical ones.how can i get it???is there any other way to do this without creating another table???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by identical you mean pairs like (white, white) perhaps this is what you want:

```
SELECT a.color, b.color
FROM colors a
CROSS JOIN colors b
WHERE a.color != b.color
```

If by identical you additionally mean preserve only one of (white, black) or (black, white) perhaps this is what you want:

```
SELECT a.color, b.color
FROM colors a
CROSS JOIN colors b
WHERE a.color > b.color
```

The important part is to reject the elements you don't want after you perform the cross-join.

Note that *this won't create any new tables or modify existing ones*. `a` and `b` are merely two different aliases for the same table `colors`. The table has only one column `color`, but since the table is present twice in the SELECT, you need to distinguish both (conceptual, not factual!) instances of the `colors` table.

*You can't do without a* `join` (then you'd have too few rows), nor you can easily do without aliases (you have to refer to both columns to reject some rows) nor there is a reason to assign aliases.

Comment: what if i dont want to use another colomn or another table????is there any way???? @jan dvorak

Comment: @shishir_bindu you are not using two tables. This will use the same table twice (`a` and `b` are merely aliases). You can't do without joining the table with itself.

Comment: thank u.:) i didnt get the alias concept at the 1st place.but got it now. thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Combinations:

```
SELECT a.color,b.color
FROM  colors a
JOIN colors b
ON a.color < b.color
```

Permutations:

```
SELECT a.color,b.color
    FROM  colors a
    JOIN colors b
    ON a.color != b.color
```